# Clone factory and constructor arguments

Tags: contract-development, assembly, factory, clone, eip-1167

In my project I'm using an EIP-1167-enabled [Clone Factory](https://github.com/optionality/clone-factory):

```
function createClone(address target) external returns (address result) {
    bytes20 targetBytes = bytes20(target);
    assembly {
      let clone := mload(0x40)
      mstore(clone, 0x3d602d80600a3d3981f3363d3d373d3d3d363d73000000000000000000000000)
      mstore(add(clone, 0x14), targetBytes)
      mstore(add(clone, 0x28), 0x5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf30000000000000000000000000000000000)
      result := create(0, clone, 0x37)
    }
    addr = result;
}
```

It works for contracts without constructor or contracts with empty constructors.

Here is a constructor for most of my contracts:

```
constructor(
    bytes32 pRegistryGroupName,
    bytes32 pRegistryName
)
    internal
{
    m_RegistrableData.registryGroupName = pRegistryGroupName;
    m_RegistrableData.registryName = pRegistryName;
}
```

When I clone my contract, as expected, the new one doesn't contain group name nor name.

I would like to have it like:

```
function createClone(address target, bytes32 groupName, bytes32 name)
```

How can I do that?

Also I'm curious what are these addresses and what they represent, why they look like that:

- 0x3d602d80600a3d3981f3363d3d373d3d3d363d73000000000000000000000000
- 0x5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf30000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Check out this article by OpenZeppelin: [Deep dive into the Minimal Proxy contract](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/deep-dive-into-the-minimal-proxy-contract/). It goes through each EVM instruction used in the EIP-1167 bytecodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We solved this by having a one time `init` function. For full source, see [ThingFactory.sol](https://github.com/optionality/clone-factory/blob/master/test/ThingFactory.sol) and [Thing.sol](https://github.com/optionality/clone-factory/blob/master/test/Thing.sol). Basically, what you do is have this one time `init` function on your `target` contract (in the example, it would be `Thing`.) Then your factory contract calls the `init` function directly after creating the clone.

The `0x3d602d80600a3d3981f3363d3d373d3d3d363d73000000000000000000000000` and `0x5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf30000000000000000000000000000000000` are the standardized bytecode template of [EIP-1167](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1167.md). The first `0x3d602d80600a3d3981f3` of the first section is the constructor of the clone contract, which is static and just returns the bytecode from said EIP.

Source: I'm one of the developers of clone-factory and EIP-1167

Comment: I guess that instead of coding a one-time `init` function from scratch, one could also import and use OpenZeppelin's battle-tested [Initializable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/aefcb3e8aa4ee8da8e2b7022ffe4dcb57fbb0fdf/contracts/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol).